# display text in plotly if frequency less than a given number

Tags: r, plotly, shiny

I'm working on a shiny app, a part of the app displays a plotly pie chart

Is there a way to display a text instead of pie chart if the value in the pie chart is less than a particular number

I can think of is using an ifelse but I don't think its a feasible approach

```
 output$plot<-renderPlotly({
      plot_ly(selection, labels = ~Country, values = ~Freq, type = 'pie') %>%
        layout(title = paste0("Percentage of patients from"," ",selection$Country[selection$Country!='Rest of the countries']," ","v/s rest of the countries"),
               xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
               yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
    })
```

The dataframe

```
Country Freq    lon        lat          total              q

India   4   78.96288    20.593684   299 1st Quantile(1-50 occurances
Rest of the countries   295 y   y   299 y
```

Comment: What is 'the value in the pie chart'?

Comment: The values are numeric values of Frequency of one country with respect to the rest of the world

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(selectInput("select","Select:", choices=unique(mtcars$cyl), selected = c(6)),
                 uiOutput("plot1")),
  server = function(input, output) {
    data <- reactive({
      data <- mtcars[mtcars$cyl %in% input$select,]
    })
 output$plot1 <- renderUI({
   if(input$select < 6){
     print("Error")
   }else{
     plotlyOutput("plot2")
   }

 })

 output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({
   plot_ly(data(), x = ~mpg, y = ~hp, color = ~cyl)
 })

  }
)
```

I have just used another plot type from `plotly` package (scatter plot) and `mtcars` dataset as You have not provided reproducible example, neither the data. However the main concept is the same and there should not be any difference: i have used `renderUI` for `if...else...` statement which says if cyl is smaller then 6, print Error, else render plot.

In Your case instead of `input$select` you should use the value which is decisive, and if i understood correctly it is Freq.